'-depth 1' vs. `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1'
I have the following directory structure on a macOS machine:
dir1/
|- file1.txt
|- dir2/
   |- file2.txt
   |- dir3
      |- file3.txt

I then run these two find commands:
find . -depth 1 -path '*.txt'

find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -path '*.txt'

The goal is to non-recursively search for all the .txt files in dir1. If used in dir1, both commands return file1.txt, but I was told that only the second command, with -mindepth and -maxdepth, is really correct. Is it really so? Could someone explain the difference?
And the second question. If I need to search recursively, should I remove -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 entirely or should I remove -maxdepth 1 only?

What about ls -d dir1/*.txt?

It returns dir1/file1.txt. I do understand I can use ls, but the question is about find. I simply trying to understand how to use it properly.

Does find . -depth 1 -path '*.txt' really run? It doesn't give you an error? -depth doesn't take a value.

@terdon Yes, it works for me and retunrs ./file1.txt. I have double-checked it by copying and pasting it right from your comment. macOS 14.6.1, Zsh 5.9, find(1)

@jsx97, ls resolve your problem. Why you insist to use find?

@RomeoNinov because the question isn't "how do I list this file?", it is "how does find work?".

@terdon, for me this is meaningless exercise.... (with first level)

@RomeoNinov the question is not about the level at all. The OP is trying to understand how the -depth, -mindepth and -maxdepth options of find work. This is just a toy example, the question is about using find, not about finding this specific, trivial file.

-depth 1 from FreeBSD is a conditional predicate that returns true if the file being currently considered is at depth 1, but it doesn't stop find from descending below depth 1.
-mindepth 1 / -maxdepth 1 from GNU are option predicates (in GNU find terminology) that globally affect the behaviour of find. They both always return true (and in general you want them at the start and wouldn't need to rely on their outcome),

-mindepth 1 makes sure that no file at depth below 1 is ever selected / acted upon
-maxdepth 1 causes find not to descend below depth 1.

-depth 1 can be useful to perform different actions depending on depth as in:
find . -depth  1 -exec printf '"%s" is in the current directory\n' {} ';' -o \
       -depth +1 -exec printf '"%s" is below the current directory\n' {} ';'

But to only process files at depth 1,
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ...

Or the standard equivalent:
find . ! -name . -prune ...

Is what you want.
-mindepth / -maxdepth can be emulated with combinations of -depth n and -prune¹, but -mindepth/-maxdepth are far more portable than -depth n² which is FreeBSD (and derivatives such as macOS or DragonFly BSD) only so there'd little point doing that.

¹ in the case of -maxdepth, not when -depth alone (see note below) or -delete (another fairly portable BSD extension like your -path³ which implies -prune) is also in effect as -prune is ineffective with -depth.
² Not to be confused with -depth alone, an option predicate to turn on depth-first traversing which is standard.
³ -path is now standard, but not -delete yet. You don't need -path here as -name will do just as well for a pattern such as *.txt.

Thanks a lot. And what if I need to search recursively, should I remove -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 entirely? Or should I preserve the -mindepth 1 part?

To ask the same thing differently: When we search the level-1 folder non-recursively, what's the point to have -mindepth 1? Isn't -maxdepth 1 is all we need?

@jsx97, -mindepth 1 excludes the files at depth 0. In the case of find ., that's . in the case of file dir1 dir2, that's dir1 and dir2 themselves. If you know your search criteria will exclude those anyway (like because there's a ! -type d to exclude files of type directory), you can can omit it.

Ah, now I see, thanks. Here is a simple example where -mindepth 1 makes difference: find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
